# How to select the grandparent of a node using xslt

Tags: xslt, select, xpath

I'm in a situation where I can only test for the child node, but I have to apply tags to the grandparent of this child node.

I've tried using:

```
<xsl:call-template name="grandparent" select="parent::parent::node()"/>
```

and:

```
<xsl:call-template name="grandparent" select="ancestor::node [@nameofgrandparentnode]"/>
```

But neither works.

The level of the grandparent node is not fixed, so I figure I can't use [@level=#] either. Any ideas on how to select it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: -- This part has been posted as a new question:**

[xslt select grandparent node depending on an attribute value of its grandchild node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687466/xslt-select-grandparent-node-depending-on-an-attribute-value-of-its-grandchild-no)

Selecting the node using the suggestions from below worked. Thanks! However I also need to test by the attribute of the grandparent or grandchild node.

I've tried:

```
<xsl:template name"one" match="grandparentnode">
 <Tag1>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="parentNode" />
 </Tag1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="two" match="grandparentnode[*/*/@grandchildattr='attrValue']">
 <Tag2>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="parentNode" />
 </Tag2>
</xsl:template>
```

However template "two" always gets called, and "" is always inserted. Even for grandchild nodes whose attribute value is not equal to 'attrValue'.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a number of XPath expressions that you can use in an `<xsl:param>` instruction.

Comment: @highlightall The edited part isn't clear. Please, provide a complete (but as short as possible) XML document and the complete XSLT stylesheet (again, as short as possible), that repro your problem. Preferrably, ask this in a new question.

Comment: @highlightall: Also `Even for grandchild nodes whose attribute value is not equal to 'attrValue'` can't be true with this pattern `grandparentnode[*/*/@grandchildattr='attrValue']`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I've tried using:
>
> ```
> <xsl:call-template name="grandparent" select="parent::parent::node()"/>
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> <xsl:call-template name="grandparent" select="ancestor::node[@nameofgrandparentnode]"/>
> ```
>
> But neither works.

Certainly it will not "work", because the `<xsl:call-template>` instruction doesn't have a `select` attribute!

You may pass parameters using `<xsl:with-param>` children of the `<xsl:call-template>` instruction, like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="compute">
  <xsl:param name="pAncestor" select="someExpression"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

**For the `select` attribute of the `<xsl:with-param>` Use**:

For a real grandparent:

```
../..
```

for the closest ancestor element with name `someName`:

```
ancestor::someName[1]
```

for the closest ancestor element with name contained in the variable `$ancName`:

```
ancestor::*[name()=$ancName][1]
```

Comment: @highlightall: Glad it worked. Here at SO gratitude is expressed by accepting an answer. Hint: Just click on the check-mark next to the answer. :)

Comment: Cool, just did that :) Any suggestions for the edited part of the question on testing for grandchildren's attributes?

Comment: I've posted a new question on the edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687466/xslt-select-grandparent-node-depending-on-an-attribute-value-of-its-grandchild-no

Answer (score 5):

> I'm in a situation where I can only test for the child node, but I have to apply tags to the grandparent of this child node.

XSLT isn't procedural programming, so you have to think about things a little differently.

If I understand correctly, you want to inject new tags (additional child elements or attributes?) into your XML, but you want to add it to an ancestor when you find a specific descendant.  Your example code appears to try to target the grandparent once you come across the child.  Unfortunately, this may be too late.

***You may need inject the new element/attribute when engine comes across the element you want to modify (the grandparent in your case), not when it comes across the child that matches the condition (or else you'll end up adding elements or attributes to the child)***

[Consider this input](http://unindented.org/projects/xslt-tester-applet/run/) (grandparent="album", grandchild="label"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<album> 
  <title>Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band</title>  
  <artist>The Beatles</artist>  
  <year>1967</year>  
  <labels> 
    <label>Parlophone</label>  
    <label>Capitol</label> 
  </labels> 
</album>
```

I want to modify the `album` based on whether a certain `label` is present.  Remember the general format for targeting nodes is: `target-node[target-condition]`.  To modify any `album` elements that have a `Capitol` label grandchild element, I'd use this:

```
album[*/label='Capitol']
```

So consider this stylesheet to add a new attribute and 2 new child elements to `album`'s that match my condition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="album[*/label='Capitol']"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="new-attribute">A Capitol Record</xsl:attribute>  
      <new-element1/> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>  
      <new-element2/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (manually formatted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<album new-attribute="A Capitol Record"> 
  <new-element1/> 
  <title>Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band</title>  
  <artist>The Beatles</artist>  
  <year>1967</year>  
  <labels> 
    <label>Parlophone</label>  
    <label>Capitol</label> 
  </labels> 
  <new-element2/>
</album>
```

Some sandbox test resources:

- http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

  - To see what nodes a given XPath expression actually targets
- http://unindented.org/projects/xslt-tester-applet/run/

  - To try out a stylesheet

Comment: @Bert F: +1 for good answer and explanation about correct approach.

Comment: @Alejandro - Thanks - check out those test resources - I find them extremely convenient and useful for experimenting.

Comment: @highthlightall - Thanks! Note that I updated the stylesheet to fix some sloppy (lazy) code.  The apply-templates line the 2nd template should have been to be split to process attributes separate from child elements (so that new attributes and elements could be added at the proper times).  Fixed now.

Comment: @Bert F: If you really want to pretify yuor stylesheet then you should use literal result elements like: `<album new-attribute="A Capitol Record">`

Comment: @Alejandro - true, but I prefer the more general approach just in case (1) you want to apply the `xsl:template` to multiple matched elements, e.g. `album[...]|single[...]` and keep/copy what was matched, and (2) `album` might have attributes we want to keep/copy in addition to adding a new attribute.