# Getting the parent node attributes in XSL

Tags: xslt, parent, nodes

In my XML I have the following:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c something="false">
      <d>
        <e>
          <f>someResult</f>
        </e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Now in the XSL within a loop I can do the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="f"></xsl:value-of>
```

But how can I get the attribute in c?

I've tried doing the following

```
<xsl:value-of select="////@something"></xsl:value-of>
```

As well as trying parent and nothing seems to be working. Can you get parent nodes like this?

Also, I cannot just do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/a/b/c/@something"></xsl:value-of>
```

As there can be multiple of c.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To move up the tree you use ".." per level ie in this instance probably

```
select="../../../@something"
```

You can also select an ancestor node by name (approx)

```
select="ancestor::c[1]/@something"
```

See http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3672992 for further examples

Answer (score 12):

**Use**:

```
ancestor::c[1]/@something
```

This selects the attribute named `something` of the first (from the current node upwards) ancestor named `c`.

Comment: @AkashTantri, no, `ancestor::c` is the node-list of *all* ancestor nodes that are named "c".  `ancestor::c[1]` selects the nearest "c" ancestor of the current node.