# XSL - add new node to the grand-parent node in XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Given XML like:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>some keyword</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I need to add new node to the parent node of a in case if node c contains text "keyword", so it will look like

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>some keyword</c>
  </b>
</a>
<x> new node X </x>
```

I can match the text with expression:

```
<xsl:template match="//a/b/c[matches(text(),'\.*keyword\.*')]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:element name="x">
    <xsl:text> new node </xsl:text>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and this results in

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>some keyword</c>
    <x> new node X </x>
  </b>
</a>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You mean you want to add the "x" node to the parent of "a", not to node "a",  right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `x` element while matching `a` 's parent. You can refer to any child element or attribute inside a predicate. What I mean is that you have to take a peek at what's inside a's parent while copying it. Doing it while copying the a, b or c element is just too late.

The following stylesheet should do the trick. I don't have any XSLT2.0 capable processor on me right now so I can't check it but you should be able to see the logic in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates ></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//*[matches(a/b/c/text() , 'keyword')]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates ></xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:element name="x">
            <xsl:text> new node </xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I did slightly different, but generat idea is clear.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672992/how-to-select-the-grandparent-of-a-node-using-xslt that was useful as well.